# Does specifying collection size in a stream's .collect improve performance?

Tags: java, list, performance, collections

Should I prefer

```
List<?> tableList = list.stream()
                .map(row -> getRowModified(row, activeLimits))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(previouslyDefinedListSize)));
```

instead of

```
List<?> tableList = list.stream()
                .map(row -> getRowModified(row, activeLimits))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in terms of performance gains?

Comment: Did it speed up your program significantly? If so, **yes**. [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/?s=race+your+horses).

Comment: Theoretically yes.  Provided that the size estimate is accurate.  In practice, if you are concerned about performance, you shouldn't restrict yourself to stream-based solutions.  An old-fashioned loop is likely to be faster ... with current JVMs.

Comment: There is an overhead to using Stream. That overhead far exceeds the performance difference of two shows solutions, so if you are down to micro-optimized the creation of an `ArrayList`, you shouldn't be using Stream at all. This is a great example of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: `collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(previouslyDefinedListSize)))` only works reasonable if a) you know the expected size and b) are not running parallel (as with a parallel stream, you would oversize the temporary lists). However, if that scenario is your concern, you can use `list.stream() .map(…) .toList()` (JDK 16) or `Arrays.asList(list.stream() .map(…) .toArray())` which works reasonable in either case.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, If we see code, `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(previouslyDefinedListSize)` should be faster (theoretically), due to

```
  public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new Collectors.CollectorImpl(
        ArrayList::new, // here we create ArrayList with 10 elements
        List::add, // here we recreate array in ArrayList when we don't have enougth capacity
        (var0, var1) -> { // and here two
            var0.addAll(var1);
            return var0;
        }, CH_ID);
  }
```

**Second**, I do not sure it so big differents in the most of cases, but `Collectors.toList()` is a quite easy to read then `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(previouslyDefinedListSize)`, so in my opinion better to create perfomance tests and check it is really matter for you application or not.